# Nextjs Page is loaded twice and hence fails

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I noticed that nextjs runs my pages twice ( I guess it preloads or does something similar server side) and since in its first call the props is undefined my whole page crashes and fails to load. Is that an expected behavior and hence in the beginning of each page I need to check whether props are empty (that does not sound a reasonable thing to do) or am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Please can you show the code snippet so we can help you?

Comment: The code is very big, not sure it will help, but I'm doing is that inside the getStaticProps, I fetch data from GraphQL and send part of them to the page. Do you mean that normally the page should be called twice?

Comment: Yes, because your page being called from client and build time.

Remember that `getStaticProps` is called in build time and since you coding in dev mode build time run always when refresh page.

Try set your console.log in `useEffect`, you should have only one `console.log`

if you set `console.log` in `getStaticProps` you can see log in terminal

Comment: Ok that's fine, I'm just asking is it the normal practice to always check for the props being undefined in nextjs? Because that sounds awkward to me.

Comment: I commonly do is send null prop from getStaticProps if data is empty and in page if null, I show" empty message" or loading depend my context app. You be careful with use getStaticProps, since when you'll deploy app,  your fetch data only will called in build time and keep static in your page.

Comment: if you want the data to be called whenever you access the page, you should use `getServerSideProps` or use `getStaticProps` but with property `revalidate`.

Comment: I know all this, that's not my question, my question was why my component is loaded twice, that suggests I'm doing something wrong somewhere, otherwise it should not be loaded twice once with the empty props and once with real data.